# Symfony rank mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, symfony, symfony-2.3

I am actually having loads of trouble trying to obtain the rank or position of a specific row on Symfony.

Example: player table

id - name - total
1    xxxx    100
2    yyyy    200 
3    www    500

When I do the following thing on the terminal, it works fine:

```
SELECT id, total, name, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank FROM player p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) q ORDER BY total DESC
```

+----+-------+----------------+------+
| id | total | name           | rank |
+----+-------+----------------+------+
| 19 |  1931 | guitouman      |    1 |
|  2 |  1765 | lu             |    2 |
|  1 |  1583 | Seyaa          |    3 |
| 17 |  1532 | coucou lapinou |    4 |
| 11 |  1494 | the moine eau  |    5 |
|  7 |  1446 | alien          |    6 |
|  3 |  1415 | Saiyya           |    7 |
| 50 |  1231 | dfdf           |    8 |
| 20 |  1230 | Jrm            |    9 |
| 16 |  1221 | Ragnar         |   10 |
|  6 |  1182 | arachati       |   11 |
|  8 |  1025 | momo           |   12 |
| 10 |   789 | kingrom        |   13 |
| 13 |   777 | le seur        |   14 |
| 53 |   743 | aaa            |   15 |
| 14 |   568 | Rakhamo        |   16 |
|  9 |   466 | sapeur coco    |   17 |
| 12 |   446 | chamboul       |   18 |
| 51 |   321 | sdfdsf         |   19 |
| 54 |   132 |                |   20 |
| 52 |    46 | sdfsdf         |   21 |
| 48 |     0 | dragma         |   22 |
+----+-------+----------------+------+

The probleme is to get this working in Symfony2 where the "@" or "Set" keyword is not recognized. I have tried this :

```
$query -> $this->_em->createQuery('SET @rownum := 0;SELECT id, total, rank FROM SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, id, totalTroopRecieved FROM clan ORDER BY total;')->setParameter('id', $this->getId());
```

return $query->getResult();

Which gives this error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 24: Error: Expected IdentificationVariable | ScalarExpression | AggregateExpression | FunctionDeclaration | PartialObjectExpression | "(" Subselect ")" | CaseExpression, got '@'
```

I feel desperate .. Spending 2 days for this when i know it works via sql queries but not on symfony makes me mad ..

I tried NUMBER_ROW() or RANK() function but it does not seem to work on Mysql.

Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: Just use a native query http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. I did a native query above but it won't accept keywords like "@" or "SET" .. Help please

Comment: In that case you will have to use DBAL query http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html. And if that does not work then you will have to create your own database connection and run the query outside of doctrine and symfony classes. Personally I hate Doctrine, but then I'm a database developer from way back and hate ORMs on principle.